# Dependency Tracking when using Task.Run in ASP.NET

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have a requirement to use Task.Run(...) to force some non-async code to run in parallel with some other async code.

```
   var task1 = Task.Run(() => synchronous code);
   var task2 = await DoSomethingAsync();

   await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

The dependency calls in the sync synchronous code are not being tracked.  It seems the Application Insights SDK (2.4) uses [System.Diagnostics.Activity](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource/src/System/Diagnostics/Activity.cs).  Is there a way create a new activity start/stop it so that in the synchronous code, the Activity.Current is setup properly and dependency telemetry is associated with the correct parent?

**PS** I cannot change the synchronous code to be asynchronous. It is calling into Microsoft CRM and the CRM SDK functions I am using do not have asynchronous versions.

Comment: I was reviewing some telemetry this morning and it *may* be working. Perhaps I was looking at sampled telemetry previously.

Comment: even async you should still get tracked dependencies, they just might not be linked to a request, if async things are going on and the http request completed before the async stuff did?